# Option / Preference to toggle folder summary at base of finder window in OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, finder

When i did i clean install from osx 10.8 to 10.10 a year or so ago i lost the option to have a summary of the folder i was in at the bottom of the finder window. Recently i seem to have pressed a short cut that has brought back the summary, but i have no idea how i did it.. any ideas ?

I have included a image of the summary bar below :

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a "folder summary bar" but the "Status Bar". It shows the number of items in the opened folder and the available free space on the volume containing the folder. To toggle visibility of the **Status Bar** use either the key combination <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (en_US keyboard layout) or the Finder menu View > Hide/Show Status Bar.